# ASP.NET MVC view - get data from dynamic expando object showing Id's not names from another table EF class

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, class, razor

I populated my view with dynamic expando using Entity Framework classes. I have two tables `tribe` and `Asserah`.

`Tribe` has `Id` and `tribeName` columns where as `Asserah` has `Id` , `Asserahname` and `Tribeid`. Both tables have primary key on column `Id` but no FK.

My controller is passing data to the view like this:

```
public ActionResult ViewAll()
{
    dynamic dy = new ExpandoObject();
    dy.asserah = GetAllAsserash();
    dy.tribe = GetAllTribes();
    return View(dy);
}
```

View is like this:

```
@foreach (Asserah item in Model.asserah) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.AsserahName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TribeId)
            *@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TribeName)@*
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.AsserahId }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.AsserahId }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.AsserahId })
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

I actually add

```
[NotMapped]
public Tribe TribeName { get; set; }
```

to `Asserah` EF class to display it in view but it is not showing any value

Can anyone help me out to get `TribeName` instead of `TribeId`?

BR

Comment: In your action, does `dy` contain data? Have you inspected it under a debugger?

Comment: @mxmissile yes for sure it has values. thats why it showing TribeId but when i replace it with TribeName it is showing epty column

Comment: @mxmissile any idea ??